# Сохранение данных при возврате

Tags: javascript, jquery, site

Есть последовательность из 4 страниц html: main_page, day_page, para_page, name_page. На страницах все работает, но когда на андроиде нажимать на `кнопку назад` то данные не сохраняются.

Как решить проблему с помощью js либо jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно чтобы сохранялись данные в полях можете использовать, что-то вроде этого:

```
$(function() {
  function serialize() {
    var obj = {};

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(id, el) {
      var $el = $(el);
      obj[$el.attr('name')] = $el.val();
    });

    sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(obj));
  }

  function deserialize() {
  console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('data'))
    var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data', '{}'));

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

      $('input[name="' + i + '"]').val(obj[i]);
    }
  }

  $('input[type="text"]').change(function() {
    serialize();
  });

  deserialize();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vntekhm1/2/